# Relative junctions

Tags: windows-8, junction

I would like to create junctions that are based on the relative path?

This way when I copy a folder all the junctions contained within are copied and point to valid data(Which is in the parent folder).

```
Parent Folder
  A
    Contains a junction to something in B
  B
    Something
```

If I copy the above the junction turns into a normal empty folder.

(the file system is a ReFS)

Comment: I don’t believe NTFS junctions support relative paths, and ReFS doesn’t seem to have added that ability either.

Answer (score 3):

Do you absolutely have to use junctions, rather than symlinks?

Symbolic links can point to relative paths.  And after you move the symlink, the relative path is traversed starting from the symlink's new location.

Comment: I have to create a relative alias from one directory to another. Symlinks don't seem to work with directories.

Comment: To create a directory symlink, use `mklink /d`

Comment: When I do this and I copy the folder the link turns into a normal folder that is empty. Same issue as before. I also want to be able to zip up the links and retain the whole structure.

Comment: Copy it on the command prompt using `copy /l` or `robocopy /sl` and it'll stay a symlink.  Directory symlinks look like regular directories to programs that are not symlink aware -- otherwise, they wouldn't be very useful.  Windows Explorer traverses the symlinks -- and maybe your ZIP program as well.